# Как выбрать внутри тегов script и получить данные в них?

Tags: python

Есть такой код html страницы:

```
<script></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 86193;
    var hour,min,sec;
    var timer = $.timer(
        function() {
            count--;
            hour = parseInt(count/3600);
            min = parseInt((count - hour*3600)/60);
            sec = parseInt(count - (hour*3600+min*60));
            $('.count_hour').html(hour);
            $('.count_min').html(min);
            $('.count_sec').html(sec);
        },
        1000,
        true
    );
</script>
```

Надо достать число из `count = 86193`
Как это можно сделать?
И если заголовок вопроса не отвечает содержимому то напишите внизу как вы это вы его написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = ("var count = 86193;")
start = 'count = '
end = ';'
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
print(result)
```

Comment: А если там не будет 861943, а допустим 1.

Comment: @Sasha294 Без разницы. Все что между start и end.

Comment: очень негибкий RegEx. `account = 11;` или `count = "str";` - тоже спарсит, хотя не должно, `var count=11;` и `var count =11;` не спарсит, хотя было бы логично их разобрать...

Comment: @MaxU Оно работает и пусть работает